# Error with PHP Mailing script

Tags: php, html, forms, web

my issue is with the php script. For some reason instead of sending the email it spits out the code. 
You can test it here: http://tgcalliance.net16.net/contact.html
I also do have php installed on the server: http://tgcalliance.net16.net/Untitled-1.php
I have tried everything to get this to work. 
I am stuck guys :/

Comment: Spits out the code? Then I'm blind. All I see is the following message: `Message sent!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working for me..

I got: Message sent!

By the way, put some sort of spam protection on your contact form. I was able to spam the e-mail. It's bad for your mail server and for you because I can spam e-mails into your mailbox.

For your spam control: http://www.phpcaptcha.org/try-securimage/

Comment: Yeah I see it's working.. Some reason it won't work for me. Maybe it's because its hosted on my home server?

Comment: Clear your cache, restart your computer. Or hit Ctrl + F5, and do a hard refresh. By the way, for your spam control, I added a link in my original post to a free captcha. I strongly advise you use it.